# C++: Placement for non-inline template methods

Tags: c++, templates, include

Suppose I have a class with a method template:

```
//file: X.h
class X{

    int x;
    //... more members and non-template functions

    template<typename T>
    void foo(T t){ //Error, cannot define the method here. Declaration is okay
        Y y = ...;
    }
}

//file Y.h
class Y {
    X x;
}
```

Due to circular class dependencies (the body of foo depends on Y and Y depends on X), I cannot define the method template `foo` where I declared it (Please do not question the design now).

So, where to put the definition of `foo` in this case? I cannot put it to the other definitions into the .cpp file or linking will fail.

My solution is to create a new header file, e.g. "X.hpp" and only add the definition of the template method into it. In this file, I include "X.h" and "Y.h". Now, whenever I need the class X, I simply include only "X.hpp" which will in turn include the other necessary h files.

So my question is: Is this the correct/best way to do it? It somehow bugs me that I have a .hpp file for only a single method template definition, but it seems to be the only possible way in case of circular type dependencies. Please again: Do not question the design by saying "it would be best to avoid circular type dependencies" or stuff like that. The question is: IF I have these dependencies, what is the best way to handle single method templates.

Comment: Why don't you use forward declaration and pointer to Y class?

Comment: While you explicitly asked for no criticism in your design, I am going to jump forward and state that if the two types are so closely related, you can consider providing a single header file with both classes. (This is not a criticism on the *logical* design, but rather a hack for the *physical* design)

Comment: @Danil: Well, that is the implementation. There may always be implementations where a forward decl does not suffice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without questioning the design:

```
//file: X.h
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H
class X{

    int x;
    //... more members and non-template functions

    template<typename T>
    void foo(T t);
};

#include "Y.h"

template<typename T>
void X::foo(T t){ //Error, cannot define the method here. Declaration is okay
    Y y = ...;
}

#endif


//file Y.h
#ifndef Y_H
#define Y_H

#ifndef X_H
#error "Please include X.h"
#endif

class Y {
    X x;
}

#endif
```

There's no need for the extra file.

Comment: @gexicide in case someone include Y.h before X.h, they will get an error. That part is to signal to the user that he's supposed to include X.h

Comment: I see. But that puts a burden onto the user of the classes. He has to explicitly include a header himself (X.h) that he might not use at all, right? And what if class Y has such a template method itself or a cycle with three classes exist? What I am aiming for: I am looking for a generally applicable solution that will work with the weirdest dependency cycles. Is the no-extra file approach applicable in all cases of weird dependencies?

Comment: @gexicide he does use that header. He can't use Y if he doesn't include X, because Y needs the definition of X. No burden, you include what you use.

Comment: yes, but in my version, he would only explicitly include Y. Y would in turn include X. Imagine some client code that is only interested in functionality of Y that is not related to X. That client code would naturally only include Y. Now, that code will fail to compile. So the client code programmer has to explicitly include a file (X.h) that he is not interested in at all. I never needed to do such things in my code, yet, and it feels somehow strange. Is this common practice?

Comment: @gexicide I stopped reading after the first sentence. There is not code that is only interested in Y and not X, because Y doesn't exist without X.

Comment: of course, but consider Y having other members of other classes and the client code is only interested in these members or simply wants to call some method of Y. Maybe the X object inside Y is private and client code cannot interact with it directly. It seems strange to include a file which I cannot use anyway (since the member is private).

Comment: @gexicide it doesn't matter. You need a full definition of the class if you want a member object. An alternative is to make the member a pointer, in which case you don't need to include the header. But as the code is now, it's not possible (as per the language specs)

Comment: I know. I think we're talking about different things :). The problem I have is that the client code using Y has to include X, even if it does not use it at all. In my solution, X is included by Y, so a client .cpp file does not have to include X explictly - it is included implicitly by Y. Suppose you include <iostream> and get an error that you also have to include <istream> and <ostream> just because iostream uses them. That would be nasty, right? The same here: Just because Y uses X, that does not mean that I want to include X explicitly when including Y - I want Y to handle that.

Comment: @gexicide IT DOES USE IT!!!! That like saying you use a car without using the wheels... This is getting very non-constructive.

Comment: well, of course, it uses it - internally! But the client does not have to know about that! I also drive a car that uses some weird electronics inside but I do not have to know about that - it just works. Your solution exposes the implementation detail that X is used by Y to the client code.

Comment: @gexicide ah, then you're looking for the pimpl idiom. That masks implementation details, not your version. Just because you say "I don't want to expose this" doesn't mean you can. Your code exposes the member because that's how you wrote it. This is the language. To have an object member, you need it's full definition. You made that choice. See here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer